# Updating mocked objects in protractor tests

Tags: json, mocking, jasmine, protractor, ngmocke2e

Just wondering if anyone has a good solution for updating mocked calls within a protractor test. I need to be able to mock a call (which I can do using ngMockE2E) but the next time the call is made, I want it to come back with different results.

```
httpbackend.when('GET', ....URL....).respond(200, results);
```

where `results` is a json object that is returned.

The first time the call is made it is coming back with the correct json. But within the same test, I want to update those results so that the next time the call is made, it returns the updated json.

Thoughts?

Comment: Also, I tried this approach: https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy/issues/20.  But logged this issue because I haven't had success with it yet.

Comment: Do you use http-backend-proxy to mock responses?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying because based on the documentation I thought I was going to be able to update the response within the same test using SyncContext but I posted the issue in my comment above because it isn't working for me.

Comment: I've left a comment on your github issue, because you have more details in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [http-backend-proxy](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy) module, it is possible to modify a response for a request with the same URL with the help of [context object](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy#using-the-context-object). To do that, you have pass a function to the `.respond()` method, which must return an array with a status and response data. Inside this function you have access to a so called context object, which is used to transfer data from Protractor test to an Angular app on a page. It is possible to modify this context object from within a test, so Angular app could receive another response.

```
var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
var proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);

// ...

// use one data for first response
proxy.context = {
    notes: notifications,
    messages: allMessages
};

proxy.when('GET', '...notificationsURL...').respond(function () {
    return [200, $httpBackend.context];
});

// here make a first call

// use another data for second response
proxy.context = {
    notes: notifications2,
    messages: allMessages2
};

proxy.syncContext(); // required, update context content for Angular app

// here make a second call
```

Note: the function you pass to `.respond()` will be serialized (converted to string) and injected on a page, by default to access a context object from Angular a variable `$httpBackend` is used. Take a look at this docs section to rename it - [Configuring the Context Object](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy#configuring-the-context-object).